# Heartbeat lost AMBARI HDP

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I lost all the heartbeats with Ambari on one of the nodes of a cluster of 4 nodes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Gie.png

I already tried to reboot the cluster, restart ambari-agent, ambari-server and restart some of the services manually like yarn. Nothing work and I am stuck now.

Ambari is in 2.1.1

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone to help you troubleshoot this issue. When you registered the hosts did you register via host name or IP? Are the ambari-agents running without error? Can each host be accessed (ping or ssh) from the ambari-server node?

Comment: Hello,
The hosts are registered by hostname and each host can access the ambari-server node
However, I have errors in the ambari-agent.log :
ERROR 2016-03-18 10:21:01,144 NetUtil.py:78 - SSLError: Failed to connect. Please check openssl library versions.

Refer to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1022468 for more details.

WARNING 2016-03-18 10:21:01,146 NetUtil.py:105 - Server at https://dl-master:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...

Comment: Can your reach this node? Via SSH or somehow?

Comment: yes, actually I was connected in ssh to this node to look for these logs.
When I go to dl-master:8440 with my browser, I faced certificate/SSL issue and can't access content